# Gnu Make target out of expanded list of files

Tags: windows, design-patterns, makefile, rules

I am grouping some type of files like:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html

about 100 sub directories...

```
CC_FILES_TO_BUILD += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/01-Application/*.c) 

ASM_FILES_TO_BUILD += $(wildcard $(PROJECT_ROOT)/01-Sources/07-Target/01-MC9S12G/04-STARTUP/01-CPL_LIB/*.s)
```

When I dump for example `CC_FILES_TO_BUILD` per rule, I get nice lists of files names:

```
E:\1983_1\02-Safety>make dump-CC_FILES_TO_BUILD
make[1]: Entering directory `E:/1983_1/02-Safety/01-Application'
E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//01-Application/01-INIT/app_init.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//01-Applicat
ion/02-MAIN/app.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//01-Application/03-FM/fm.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//01
-Application/05-SMCM/SMCM.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//01-Application/06-LIM/LIM.c  E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/0
 1-Sources//02-Services/01-CanM/can_user.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//02-Services/01-CanM/v_par.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-
 Application/01-Sources//02-Services/01-CanM/vstdlib.c E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application/01-Sources//02-Services/01-CanM/sip_vers.c ...
......make[1]: Leaving directory `E:/1983_1/02-Safety/01-Application'
```

I then build new lists out these by normal subst to get the corresponding lists of depend and obj files, like:

```
CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST = $(call unique, $(foreach src,$(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD ),
$(DEP_PATH)\$(basename $(notdir$(subst,\,/,$(SRC)))).$(MAK_FILE_SUFFIX)))
```

I then want to use these depend and obj lists as targets in rules like:

```
$(filter-out $(GCC_IGNORE_LIST), $(CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST)) :$(DEP_OUTPUT_PATH)\\%.$(MAK_FILE_SUFFIX):$(DEPEND_FORCE) |  $(DEPEND_CPP_OPTIONS_FILE) $(DIRECTORIES_TO_CREATE)
$(SEPARATOR) [depend]   $(notdir $@)
$(CPP) @$(DEPEND_CPP_OPTIONS_FILE) -undef -MM -MF "$@" -MT "$(call depend_get_target,$@)" -MT "$@" "$(getSourceFile)"
```

Then the target depend:

```
depend: $(LIB_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST) $(CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST) | $(DEPEND_CPP_OPTIONS_FILE) $(DIRECTORIES_TO_CREATE)
```

and the output:

```
E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application>make depend
* [build]       depend.cpp_options
E:\1983_1\02-Safety\01-Application>
```

apparently nothing to be done although the dependcies files(*.mak) are not there. No force or phony could solve it for me.

Comment: What doe `CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST` contain? You mentioned `CC_FILES_TO_BUILD` and `ASM_FILES_TO_BUILD` but not that variable. Also is `MAK` a typo? Also you are explicitly running `$(wildcard)` the section of manual you quoted doesn't apply at that point. It is talking about `*` expansion.

Comment: Your question is all over the place; I can't figure out what's wrong.  Please specify (a) the actual make rule you wrote, (b) what "normal subst" you are doing to create `CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST`, (c) the make command you invoke (cut/paste if it's more than just `make`, (d) the messages make prints (again please cut and paste) and (e) what is wrong with that / what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: Sorry the question was so unclear...
EtanReisner, I corrected to CC_FILES_TO_BUILD. The CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST was an example after subst(edited). Yes, I am calling wildcard function explicitly. The reference is not relevant. 
MadScientist, I edited to answer a)-d) comments. 
e) I expect calling make depend that make will execute the above target($(CC_TO_MAK_BUILD_LIST)) which tell's how to build the listed target dependencies.
Hope it is clearer.